# Send string with whitespaces as git commit message using bash

Tags: linux, string, git, bash, whitespace

I'm creating a bash script that updates a git branch, everything works fine but now i want to add the option to specify the commit message as a parameter.

I used this command first:

```
echo "Executing git commit..."
git commit -m "$1"
```

but when i sent something like this:

```
$ git.sh "testing commit message"
```

I get a bunch of errors telling me the command cannot be recognized by git.

I suppose in this case that the double quotes I added are not passing the parameter as a single string but as many, so only the first one is taken by the -m option and git tries to pass the others as commit options.

Is there a better way i can pass a multi word string as git commit message when getting it from the script arguments?

I would really appreciate any suggestion you have.

Comment: I think your bug is not in the code you quoted, because double-quotes absolutely should protect the parameter expansion from being treated as multiple words.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Aliases?

Comment: also, debug your setup with an `echo xxxx"$1"XXXX` before the call to git. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quotes are removed when the command is evaluated by the shell.

Use something like

```
git commit -m "'$1'"
```

Comment: for me this adds single quotes to message, but I solved by adding just spaces around the variable: git commit -m " $msg "

Comment: If you use this command in an npm script, you can't do it like that. Instead, you have to use double quotes and escape them, like so:

`"postdeploy": "git add package.json package-lock.json && git commit -m \"Docs %npm_package_version%\""`

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
git commit -m "$(echo $@)"
```